# How to Select only Id's with linq when there is List in List

Tags: c#, linq

I want to select only id's from List of objects in another List: 
https://dotnetfiddle.net/Leu1AD

I need to use only linq Select or SelectMany:

```
var obj = offices.Select(p => new {Id = p.Id, Employess = p.Employess}).ToList();
```

Currently I get following result:

```
[
  {
    "Id":1,
    "Employess":[
      {
        "Id":1,
        "FirstName":"a",
        "LastName":"b"
      },
      {
        "Id":2,
        "FirstName":"c",
        "LastName":"d"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id":2,
    "Employess":[
      {
        "Id":3,
        "FirstName":"e",
        "LastName":"f"
      },
      {
        "Id":4,
        "FirstName":"g",
        "LastName":"h"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

But I need this result:

```
[
  {
    "Id":1,
    "Employess":[
      {
        "Id":1
      },
      {
        "Id":2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "Id":2,
    "Employess":[
      {
        "Id":3
      },
      {
        "Id":4
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Do you have any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One method to get the result to be the format you want is along the lines of

```
var obj = offices.Select(p => new {Id = p.Id, Employess = p.Employess.Select(y=> new {y.Id})}).ToList();
```

ends up as

```
[{"Id":1,"Employess":[{"Id":1},{"Id":2}]},{"Id":2,"Employess":[{"Id":3},{"Id":4}]}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You need a second `Select` that only selects the Employee `Id`.

```
var obj = offices.Select(o => new {Id = o.Id, Employess = o.Employess.Select(e => new { Id = e.Id })});
```

Answer (score 2):

alter your line

```
var obj = offices.Select(p => new {Id = p.Id, Employess = p.Employess}).ToList();
```

to

```
var obj = offices.Select(p => new {Id = p.Id, Employess = p.Employess.Select(x=>new{Id=x.Id})}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

To have the expected result just replace:

```
Employess = p.Employess
```

With

```
Employess = p.Employess.Select(e => new { e.Id })
```

Finally you have this LINQ statement:

```
var obj = offices.Select(p => new {Id = p.Id, Employess = p.Employess.Select(e => new { e.Id })}).ToList();
```